# locking messing up serialport handles

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, serial-port

I have a question on concept design using system.timers, and threading.

consider the following pseudo code (it is in C# but as I'm asking conceptual, I am not checking syntax for accuracy)

```
class exam{
    private Serialport sp;
    private readonly object lckObj = new object();
    System.Timer timer;

    public exam()
    {
        // actually I think this lock is not needed as
        // the object gets created on thread creation... 
        // a yay-nay on this would be cool too, I figure it
        // can't hurt to lock
        lock(lckObj) 
        {
            // do stuff
            sp = new Serialport(params);
            sp.DataRecieved += sp_dataRec;

            timer = new system.Timer(someNumber);
            timer.Elapsed += timeElap;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            // also from my understanding in how enabled 
            // works, this is redundant and I can remove
            timer.Start(); 
        }
    }

    private void timeElap()
    {
        lock(lckObj)
        {
            if(sp.Closed) sp.Open();
        }
    }

    private void sp_dataRec()
    {
        lock(lckObj)
        {            
           //do stuff to process message
           // set success bool
           bool success = outcomeOfProcessing;
           callResponse(success);
        }
    }

    private void callResponse(bool success)
    {   
        if(!sp.IsOpen) sp.Open();

        // logic to assemble response hinged on success
        sp.Write("something");
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is have the timer come through and check every few seconds to make sure the port ins't closed. This has come about because "something" no clue what is closing the port- found this by attaching a port monitor and it just pops closed at random. No errors pop or anything (no timer suppression errors, I'm looking to add timer). No clue why this is happening (also never in code am I .Close(); ing the port)

However as I am thinking this trough I am now concerned that if I lock to check on the serialport to check state, as well as locking on it to send message back- will this inhibit my data received handle, or will it still queue accordingly

For example I lock on the serial port to check state, and just slightly after enough to miss maybe on byte my data in pops and instead of getting

.1234.

I get

1234.

Note the dot's being start/stop bytes

Edit: I forgot to mention my other concern is the Sytem.Timer suppressing errors of serialport interference

Edit2: I removed the lock from the callResponse- as I am looking at it again calls to the response would be withing the already locked method- so it should be thread-safe still- Correct?

Comment: `I am not checking syntax for accuracy`: Ok, but that makes it rather difficult to tell if errors in the code you posted are actual errors in your real code or not. For example, you create your `SerialPort` in `exam`, but it's local to that method. It wouldn't be accessible anywhere else. I assume that's just a "didn't check for accuracy" thing, but I don't know. Post something that is at least valid code please.

Comment: `This has come about because "something" no clue what is closing the port`. I'm going to guess...USB/serial port adapter?

Comment: @MattBurland the serial port object is now moved to the correct position- that was an oops. There are no errors. Ever. So I'm not asking if what I have done already is correct. FWIW the only thing different is I added the locks, the lock object, and the timer. So please just take it at face value that it works fine. The problem, as outlined in my description, is that randomly, while watching a serial monitor, is that it comes through "com port closed". At no time do I ever close the port. Also yes, you are correct, it is a USB-Serial adapter.

Comment: it is also for the most part syntax correct- again I find the struggle of posting simplified example coed with posting my entire class... rather beyond frustrating. My code compiles and runs- it's not a build error or runtime error. it works except outlined problem. I just wanted to avoid getting downvote nailed bc I oopsed something like in orig post which was sp.Write('something"); which I boldly assume some1 out there would come through and remark on and downvote as it should be "something"

Comment: I'm sorry but syntax nazi's here and down votes drive me ape-sh**. I'm asking a concept question. Not code. Will locking block my input buffer?

Comment: I doubt locking is causing a problem, but I very much doubt it will solve your problem either. It won't solve the problem if the port closes while you are trying to read from it. And, if you port is getting closed, and then you reopen it, you will undoubtedly lose some of the data. Serial port over USB are a major pain and are notoriously flaky. Just make sure everything is wrapped with `try...catch` blocks and try and be tolerant of the inevitable failures.

Comment: If you had a tire on your car that would suddenly go flat at random times, would you carry a pump so you could re-inflate it, or would you *fix the freaking tire*? Your check-for-closed-and-reopen technique here cannot be made to work reliably. Whatever's closing the port could close it in the middle of a send or receive operation, which would result in incomplete data. You need to find the cause of the random closure and fix it, not try to patch around it with something that can't be made to work.

Comment: @MattBurland I have not added the locks yet- the question which doesn't seem to be appearing/coming off right is. *IF* I ad those locks, would that block my input buffer? or Would the input buffer (data received event) still go through as it does without locks/timer etc... the code posted are the changes I have in mind to fix the issue- but I cannot find documentation on if that would happen or not. Am I making sense? I rally wish there was a SerialPort.StateChanged event, but there isn't :/ I want to make sure I'm not going to truncate my input reads/buffer

Comment: @JimMischel I completely agree- however (if in industry you should know this) sometimes the people who delegate what you can/cannot do do not want to fork the $ or allow the system to be re-architect-ed... Ideally this entire thing shouldn't even be on .net- it is a backwards approach to an engineering solution that all the previous coders who've posed this have been ignored and let go. I'm making lemonade.

Comment: The `SerialPort` buffers data. It will have received the data already and stored it in an internal buffer before it calls your receive event handler. So the lock will not cause a problem unless you hold it so long that the data buffer fills up.

Comment: @JimMischel thank you very much- that was bottom line what I needed to know. If you'd like to pose as answer I'll mark it.

Comment: I understand the expediency problem. I, too, am working with some code that evolved through a lot of quick changes. What I said still holds: you cannot make your code work reliably because the port could close at any time: 100 milliseconds after you opened the port, for example, or somewhere in the middle of sending or receiving data. You really need to track down the cause because patching around it can't possibly work.

Comment: `IF I ad those locks, would that block my input buffer?` - 1) Try it and see. 2) I doubt it'll be a problem, but it won't fix your problem anyway.

Comment: @MattBurland I have no way to even fathom testing that- I would need to get my timer to fire the lock at literally nano seconds (or less) before the data comes in to see if it would happen- think of how long it takes to do the timer elapsed event- almost instant- and with the datarecieved blocking the timer it wouldn't interrupt the data received event. How would I test this? And it won't fix the problem in that "whatever" closes it will still do so, but it will fix in that if it gets closed it will come back and open it again- again I cannot do the ideal alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SerialPort` buffers data. By the time your received event handler is called, the underlying control has already read the data from the serial port and stored it in an internal buffer. The lock will not cause a problem unless you hold it so long that the data buffer fills up.

That said, I must repeat what I said in comments: your proposed solution can't be made to work reliably. If something external to your program is disabling the serial port asynchronously, it can happen at any time regardless of the state your program is in. You have a one-second timer that checks to see if the port is closed and, if so, re-opens it. That might solve the problem "most of the time," but there's no guarantee that the port won't be closed immediately after you re-open it, or it could be closed while your program is in the middle of sending or receiving data. Remember: your code doesn't do the actual send or receive, but rather reads from or writes to a buffer that is managed by the underlying `SerialPort` control.

You really need to find out what is causing the serial port to be closed, and prevent that from happening. That's the only way to make your program reliable.

Comment: +1 yeah - could even be a hardware or driver problem on the test box and so not affect delivered apps.

Comment: Yup- and I agree with you both- hands tied- thank you very much!